# REGEXP_LIKE to match xml tag content that is not like a specific string

Tags: regex, xml, plsql

I'm trying to do a regular expression matching with REGEXP_LIKE and I'm looking for a regexp to find if the value of a specific tag is not a specific string.
For example:

```
<person>
   <name>John</name>
   <age>40</age>
</person>
```

My goal is to validate that the name tag's value is not John, so the REGEXP_LIKE would return true for input xmls where name is not John.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: What has this got to do with `PL/SQL`? Are you storing the *whole XML data* in a single row in the database?

Comment: Yes, in this scenario I store the whole xml data in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do this is to simply negate the regex search:

```
... WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE('column_name', '<name>John</name>')
```

However, as should be mentioned every time a question like this is posted, it's generally [a bad idea to parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610). If you find yourself constructing more complex regex patterns to search this XML data, then you should:

- Use [an XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32374471/1954610) instead of regular expressions, or
- Change how you are storing the data! Make `person.age` a separate table column; don't bung the entire XML structure into a single place.

Comment: I used the same solution you suggested, however I was curious in finding a way to see if negate can be done inside the regex.

Comment: This is easily done with look-aheads, but I don't know if `PL/SQL` regular expressions support this. Something like: `<name>(?!John)[^<]*</name>` ... But as I say, using regular expressions to parse XML is asking for trouble.

Comment: If the language does not support this regex feature, then you could also achieve this with a much more verbose pattern: `<name>([^J]|J[^o]|Jo[^h]|Joh[^n]|John[^<])[^<]*</name>`

Comment: Thank you very much! The first solution <name>(?!John)[^<]*</name> works as a charm.